What is the standard behavior when a JTAG instruction is violated?
How does the IEEE-1149 standard regulates the TAP-controller behavior if the instruction register  in the SELECT-DR or CAPTURE-DR states contains a value that does not correspond to any instructions?

The point "d" a in the section 8.1.1 of the IEEE1149.1-2013 standard states that
Instruction binary codes that are not otherwise required to provide control of test logic shall be equivalent to the BYPASS instruction
